# How wordpress made action/filter hooks? (attaching your functions within their function)

Tags: php, wordpress

I am interested in what concept has Wordpress used to create an awesome feature they have: action and filters.

Does anyone know how they work and how to create similar feature in any non-wordpress app/project?

P.S. Just thought to double clarify, just in case, I know how to use them within wordpress, I am interested how they actually work.

Thank you!

Comment: Yes, I know.  It's just a rudimentary event's system.  it's pretty simple, you have a class (Mediator) that stores actions in an array, then when someone calls `add_action(action, callback, priority)` you add a callback to that array `$hooks = ['action' => [[callback, priority], [callback, priority]]` then before triggering action (`do_action`) you sort callbacks by priority.  And it's a pretty simple matter of invoking the callback with `call_user_func_array` etc.. on each callback for that action.

Comment: That said, this is way to broad a question for SO.

Comment: Thank you ArtisticPhoenix, very broad answer you gave below, just what I hoped to find out about the concept :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this:

```
class mediator{
    
    protected $actions = [];
    
    protected static $instance;
    
    private function __construct(){}
    private function __clone(){}

    public static function getInstance(){
        if(!self::$instance) self::$instance = new self;
        
        return self::$instance;
    }

    public function addAction($action, $callback, $priorty=10){
        $this->actions[$action][] = [
            'callback' => $callback,
            'priorty' => $priorty
        ];
    }

    public function doAction($action, ...$args=[]){
        if(!isset($this->actions[$action])) return;

        usort($this->actions[$action], function($a,$b){
            return $a['priorty'] <=> $b['priorty'];
        });
 
        foreach($this->actions[$action] as $action){
                call_user_func_array($action['callback'], $args);
        }
    }
}

$mediator = mediator::getInstance();

//Testing

function bar($arg1, $arg2){
    echo $arg1." ".$arg2."\n\n";
}
//callback using a standard function
$mediator->addAction('foo', 'bar');

//callback with a closure
$mediator->addAction('foo', function($arg1, $arg2){
    echo $arg1." ".$arg2."\n\n";
});

class foo{
    function bar($arg1, $arg2){
        echo $arg1." ".$arg2."\n\n";
    }
    
    static function sbar($arg1, $arg2){
        echo "static ".$arg1." ".$arg2."\n\n";
    }
}

 //callback with obj and method
$mediator->addAction('foo', [new foo, 'bar']);

//static callback with class name and method
$mediator->addAction('foo', ['foo', 'sbar'], 1);

//execute the hook (with arguments)
$mediator->doAction('foo', "bar", "baz");
```

Output

```
static bar baz

bar baz

bar baz

bar baz
```

[Sandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/a9e87864caa0e3c672511ad86d6e3f74739606b6)

Note that I used some shortcuts specific to:

- PHPv5.6  `...` variadic, (not sure if that is the right spelling)

But it basically wraps the arguments in an array ( or unwraps them, depending how it's used).  If your not on 5.6 or above (you should be on 7) but you can do the same thing with this:

```
  public function doAction($action, $args=[]){
       $args = func_get_args();
       $action = array_shift($args);
       //...
  }
```

Basically we are taking all the arguments (After the first) and passing them to `call_user_func_array`.  Using the `...` just makes it easier to do that.

[Sandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/65988f0dc1872d6eafdcc6318a7b9b7f325040e0)

- PHPv7+ `<=>` spaceship.

This is an new comparison operator that returns  `a<b=-1` `a==b=0` and `a>b=1`  So it just takes care of the search sorting a bit cleaner :

```
usort($this->actions[$action], function($a,$b){
   return $a['priorty'] <=> $b['priorty'];
});
//functionally the same as 
usort($this->actions[$action], function($a,$b){
     if($a['priorty'] == $b['priorty'])return 0;
     return $a['priorty'] > $b['priorty'] ? 1 : -1;
});
```

This is also a "Singleton" just because it makes things much easier for an event system. This is a class that can have only one instance loaded at one time.  You cannot call `new mediator` instead call `mediator::getInstance()`.  Because the callbacks are stored in the class, if you got a different instance, none of your callbacks would exist.  Now we could pass the `$mediator` object around, maybe even make it "global" but we can also just make it a singleton.

Also note that I registered `$mediator->addAction('foo', ['foo', 'sbar'], 1);` last, but it ran first because of the priority of 1 and the sorting...

But yea that's how "basic" of an implementation you can do and have something that functions.

AS far as WordPress goes, filters return and actions do not. That is really the main difference.

Even shortcodes, and enqueuing scripts are not all that different.

Lastly I will leave you with this:

> In software engineering, the mediator pattern defines an object that encapsulates how a set of objects interact. This pattern is considered to be a behavioral pattern due to the way it can alter the program's running behavior.
>
> Usually a program is made up of a large number of classes. Logic and computation are distributed among these classes. However, as more classes are added to a program, especially during maintenance and/or refactoring, the problem of communication between these classes may become more complex. This makes the program harder to read and maintain. Furthermore, it can become difficult to change the program, since any change may affect code in several other classes.
>
> With the mediator pattern, communication between objects is encapsulated within a mediator object. Objects no longer communicate directly with each other, but instead communicate through the mediator. This reduces the dependencies between communicating objects, thereby reducing coupling.

Comment: thank you, exactly what I hoped to hear - the name of the concept (mediator) and some examples to analyse! thank you Sir :)

Comment: Sure, it's pretty easy concept once you get the hang of it.